# XSLT 2.0 replace function returns same string when comparing special html characters

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am writing an XSLT to produce HTML for HTML Help Viewer 1.0. Some of the titles contain the `&lt;` and `&gt;` sequences. This causes loads of problems with the viewer as it converts them back to angle brackets. Having read on-line that having them as there Unicode versions will work (http://mshcmigrate.helpmvp.com/faq/notes10) I tried to use the replace function to do this and the result is the same as the input.

The code I am using is:

```
replace(replace(/*/name, '&lt;', '&#60;'), '&gt;', '&#62;')
```

The input:

```
DocumentationTest.GenericClass&lt;T&gt; Namespace
```

Outputs as:

```
DocumentationTest.GenericClass&lt;T&gt; Namespace
```

How can I perform a string replace to get this output?

```
DocumentationTest.GenericClass&#60;T&#62; Namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&lt;` and `&#60;` are two different representations of the same character. You can use replace() (or more simply, translate()) to change one character to another, but you can't use it to control how that character is represented in the serialized output - that's entirely up to the serializer. You can influence it, however, using character maps - see [xsl:character-map](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps).

Comment: I tried the character map and it outputs the angle bracket, not the escaped character sequence. So is there not a way to take a string `Test&lt;T&gt;` and output `Test&#60;T&#62;` as a string? Preferably being able to localise it to a single template.

Comment: As I tried to explain, these are different serializations of the same string. The serializer can distinguish them, the XSLT processor proper can not.

Comment: I understand they are the same thing, but I wanted it to be treated as text. Thank you for your explanation, it's not that I don't believe you. Just that I think it's weird that this can't be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior as per the XML parser itself, which executes before XSLT gets ahold of it.  If you must maintain the `&lt;` in the document, then it should be encoded as `&amp;lt;`, and a simple find and replace on all `&` symbols, replacing them with `&amp;`, should do the trick.

Comment: The output document from the XSLT does retain `&lt;` etc. However the MS Help Viewer converts these back to angle brackets and this causes problems when it is rendered. I need to convert `&lt;` in the input document to `&#60;` in the output document.

I want the angle brackets to display in the browser not the text `&lt;`.